# Django - Django-Filter template foreignkey loop

Tags: django, foreign-keys, django-filter

I have a Django FilterSet that shows per investor the investments. 
The problem is that in my template (html browser) the investors that have 0 investments are not displayed.

I'm pretty sure the problem lies in how I filter through the investment.set_all

Who can help me out :)??

many thanks to all !

models.py:

```
class Fund(models.Model):
 feeder = models.CharField(max_length=100)

 def __str__ (self):
    return  self.feeder

class Investor(models.Model):
 first_name = models.CharField(max_length = 100)
 last_name = models.CharField(max_length = 100)

def __str__ (self):
    return '%s %s' % (self.first_name, self.last_name)

class Investment(models.Model):
 feeder = models.ForeignKey(Fund, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
 investor = models.ForeignKey(Investor, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
 commitment = models.DecimalField(max_digits=20, decimal_places=2, default="1")

 def __str__ (self):
    return '%s %s' % (self.feeder, self.investor)
```

filters.py:

```
class InvestorFilter(django_filters.FilterSet):
 first_name = django_filters.CharFilter(field_name='first_name', lookup_expr='icontains')
 last_name = django_filters.CharFilter(field_name='last_name',lookup_expr='icontains')
```

views.py:

```
def investors_overview(request):
 investorfilter = InvestorFilter(request.GET, queryset=Investor.objects.all())
 return render(request, 'funds/investors.html', {'investorfilter' : investorfilter })
```

investors.html:

```
          <tbody>

            {% for investor in investorfilter.qs %}
            {% for investment in investor.investment_set.all %}
              <tr>
                <td>   {{investor.first_name}} </td>
                <td>   {{investor.last_name}}  </td>
                <td>   {{investment.feeder}} </td>
                <td>   {{investment.commitment}} </td>
              </tr>

            {% empty %}
              <tr>
                <td colspan="5"> No such investor exists</td>
              </tr>
            {% endfor %}
              {% endfor %}
        <p></p>
          </tbody>
```

Comment: What is a FilterSet? And what exactly is your desired output?  Anyway, you need to show the view that renders this template.

Comment: hi Daniel FilterSet -> . Django-Filter. Ive included my view.. thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not entirely sure what you are asking here, but I think your problem is that you have the output of investors within the investment_set loop, rather than outside. This may be more what you want:

```
{% for investor in investorfilter.qs %}
  <tr>
    <td>   {{investor.first_name}} </td>
    <td>   {{investor.last_name}}  </td>
  </tr>
  {% for investment in investor.investment_set.all %}
    <tr>
      <td colspan="2"></td>
      <td>   {{investment.feeder}} </td>
      <td>   {{investment.commitment}} </td>
    </tr>
  {% empty %}
    <tr>
      <td colspan="4"> Investor has no investments</td>
    </tr>
  {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

so that the `empty` corresponds to the inner for loop, over the investments, with an appropriate error message.

**Edit**

I'm finding it a bit hard to understand exactly what you want. Here's a solution that displays the investments on the same row as the investor, but at the cost of some duplication both of code and of output (since you now get the investor once for each investment); also I can't understand where you would want the "No such investment" message to go.

```
{% for investor in investorfilter.qs %}
  {% for investment in investor.investment_set.all %}
    <tr>
      <td>   {{investor.first_name}} </td>
      <td>   {{investor.last_name}}  </td>
      <td>   {{investment.feeder}} </td>
      <td>   {{investment.commitment}} </td>
    </tr>
  {% empty %}
    <tr>
      <td>   {{investor.first_name}} </td>
      <td>   {{investor.last_name}}  </td>
    </tr>
  {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Hi Daniel. It partly solves the problem. Indeed, the investors without any investment are now presented. though the format of the table is significantly different

Comment: How can I say : "for investment in investor.investment_set.all " show X, if null, show "no investment" ?

Comment: uhh I see, but I don't like the fact that the investment loop is on a different row than the investor loop. Can this be solved? many thanks again !